# Managing partitions on Linux

Tags: gparted

I have two OS installed on my computer, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. I want to resize my partitions to make room for another OS. I'm using gParted, the problem is i don't know which partition is used for Ubuntu and which one is used for Windows. [image]

I'm going to install Kali linux so i believe 50 Gb are enough.
I don't know how to proceed , any help would be very appreciated . 
PS: I don't want to use a virtual machine to install the third OS.

Comment: "I'm going to install Kali linux" -- No offense intended, but kali is a distro for linux experts. If you have to ask the question you're asking, kali will not be a pleasant experience, and you will find it very hard to get help. As for the answer, ntfs is a windows filesystem, so that should tell you which is which.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask, you can't afford it.

The first three partitions sda1-3 are formatted with Microsoft's NTFS and almost certainly all belong to your Windows installation. Your extended partition contains one ext4 partition, which will be your Ubuntu install. With your current configuration you will need to do some juggling to expand the extended partition backwards after shrinking sda3, because you can't have more than four primary partitions, unless you're ok with wiping out either sda3 (mostly empty anyway) or sda6 (Ubuntu). You might be able to slot a ~10GiB partition in between the Ubuntu partition and the swap partition.

*That said*, **it's overwhelmingly likely that a physical installation of Kali is neither what you want nor suitable for what you expect, and is only going to lead to a lot of unnecessary difficulty for you**, or worse. If you were in a position where it were the right path to take, you'd know it, and you'd know the answer to this question without asking it.

This other question and its answers may be helpful to you: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/73093)